# Cannot fetch ID of different products with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make an E-commerce website with PHP and AJAX but I cannot seem to fetch IDs of the products in my shop view. 
For example, my shop have 3 products with IDs 1,2,3 respectively and now on "Add to Cart" button click, I want to fetch the ID. For that I am using AJAX

I have tried several different methods and I am including my current code below. The problem is, when I click on "Add to Cart" button, it only fetches the ID of the first product, i.e. 1 no matter which product was added to cart.

```
echo "<div class='col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                                                    <div class='product-item'>
                                                        <div class='product-image-hover'>
                                                            <a href='product-details.php?id=$id' id='theLink' data-id='$id'>
                                                                <img class='primary-image' src='$realimg' alt=''>
                                                            </a><input type='text' class='hidden-id' value='$id' hidden>
                                                            <div class='product-hover'>
                                                                <button type='button' class='add-to-cart'><i class='icon icon-FullShoppingCart' ></i></button>
                                                                <a href='#'><i class='icon icon-Heart'></i></a>
                                                                <a href='#'><i class='icon icon-Help'></i></a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class='product-text'>
                                                            <h4><a href='product-details.php?id=$id'>$name</a></h4>
                                                            <div class='product-price'><span>INR $price</span></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>";
```

THE AJAX FOR THE SAME IS BELOW

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function() {
    var quantity = 1;
    var id = $('.hidden-id').val();
    alert("Product id is " + id + " and quantity is: " +quantity);
});
```

On clicking the add-to-cart button, the output is "Product id is 1 and quantity is 1"
No matter what product button I click on, the ID is always 1, how can I solve this?

Comment: use `$(this).closest('input.hidden-id').val();` instead of `$('.hidden-id').val();`

Comment: @spinsch now it gets "undefined"

Comment: use ```$(this).closest('.product-image-hover').find('input.hidden-id').val();``` instead of ```$(this).closest('input.hidden-id').val();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an attribute called: data-val into the **add to cart** button and add dynamic **id** attribute to text with class: **hidden-id** like below. And use that attributes in the script as well.

**PHP**

```
echo "<div class='col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
    <div class='product-item'>
    <div class='product-image-hover'>
        <a href='product-details.php?id=$id' id='theLink' data-id='$id'>
        <img class='primary-image'  alt='sss'>
        </a><input type='text' class='hidden-id' id='hidden_$id' value='$id' hidden>
        <div class='product-hover'>
        <button type='button' class='add-to-cart' data-val='$id'>Add to cart</button>
        <a href='#'><i class='icon icon-Heart'></i></a>
        <a href='#'><i class='icon icon-Help'></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-text'>
        <h4><a href='product-details.php?id=$id'>$name</a></h4>
        <div class='product-price'><span>INR $price</span></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>";
```

**JS**

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function() {
    var quantity = 1;
    var clickedProdId = $(this).attr('data-val');
    var id = $('#hidden_'+ clickedProdId).val();
    alert("Product id is " + id + " and quantity is: " +quantity);
});
```